# Error in github action while installing npm dependencies

Tags: github, npm, next.js, continuous-integration, github-actions

I am trying to setup actions for NextJS app using the following `yml` file

```
name: Frontend Build

on: push

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - uses: actions/setup-node@v3
        with:
          node-version: "18"
      - run: | 
          cd frontend
          npm ci
          npm run build
```

but i get the error every time `npm ci` or `npm install` is run
It says :
Run cd frontend

```
npm ERR! code E401
npm ERR! Incorrect or missing password.
npm ERR! If you were trying to login, change your password, create an
npm ERR! authentication token or enable two-factor authentication then
npm ERR! that means you likely typed your password in incorrectly.
npm ERR! Please try again, or recover your password at:
npm ERR!     https://www.npmjs.com/forgot
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you were doing some other operation then your saved credentials are
npm ERR! probably out of date. To correct this please try logging in again with:
npm ERR!     npm login

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/runner/.npm/_logs/2023-02-18T16_14_12_437Z-debug-0.log
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

i did not see anyone setting password for public npm registry.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Got it, my package-lock.json was generated back when I was using private npm registry

Comment: Can you show contents of your package file ? You are probably using a private NPM that requires a token

Answer (score -1):

You have to create an .npmrc file with proper authToken when installing a secured dependencies.

- name: "Create .npmrc"
  run: |
  echo "registry.npmjs.org/:_authToken=${NPM_TOKEN}" >> .npmrc

Then you can call npm install.